# Returning FilePath from Implicit-Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

To start a File Manager app so the user can pick which file they would like to open, I'm using the following code:

```
    Intent pickFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    pickFile.setType("file/*");
    pickFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    if (pickFile.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(pickFile,FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Did not start intent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

This works fine., but the File Manager opens in the root directory.
For the user, this entails too much clicking until the desired file is attained.

So is there any way to start the Intent maybe from a different folder, and not the root directory? Moreover, the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage) does not seem to offer a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/yourFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"),FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: When I choose 'File Commander' in the 'Open from' dialogue, the app just shows an empty screen (even though the file is there). However, when manually navigating to it, it will show up and I will be able to open it in my android program. Any clues to this behaviour ?